# Display data in two 'sequences' using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm thinking how to (because I don't have any code yet) display data from mysql database (using PHP) like this..

For example, my table `tb_services`:

```
+--------------+----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------
|      id      |        title         |          body             |     image      |
+--------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
|       1      |      service 1       |         body 1            |    img1.jpg    |
|       2      |      service 2       |         body 2            |    img2.jpg    |
|       3      |      service 3       |         body 3            |    img3.jpg    |
|       4      |      service 4       |         body 4            |    img4.jpg    |
+--------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
```

and the PHP code could be like this:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");
    mysql_select_db("db_services");

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from tb_services");

    $data = array();

    while ($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql){
        $data[] = $reg;
    }

?>
```

The result I need should be like this:

[image]

(Maybe not like that style)

Thank your for answers.

Comment: That can be (and should be) done with CSS alone. The markup should not change between the two.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$i=1;
while ($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql){
    $data[] = $reg;

  if($i%2)==1){
      echo "First Layout";
  }else{
      echo "Second Layout";
  }

 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple...

```
$odd = true;
while ($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql){
    $data[] = $reg;

    if($odd){
        $odd=false;
        //echo left layout
    }
    else{
        $odd=true;
        //echo right layout
    }
}
```